# Sublime text 2: replace text from JSON using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, json, sublimetext2

I've converted an Excel File to JSON using an online web tool. Now, I need help replacing some values from that JSON. I'm using sublime text 2.

```
{"Time (GMT-04:00)":"2010-07-06 08:30:00","Skin temp - average":"34,2043","Step Counter":172,"Sleep":"0,0","Physical Activity":1,"Energy expenditure":"11,4371","Annotations":"Running"}
```

Notice that some numbers were converted to string, because of the comma:

```
"Skin temp - average":"34,2043"
```

What I need to accomplish is to erase the quotes in all numbers, and to replace , (comma) with . (dot). Is there a way to do that using regular expressions in ST2?

Ex:

```
"Skin temp - average":34.2043
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look for:

```
"(\d+),(\d+)"
```

and replace it with:

```
$1.$2
```

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl (Cmd)</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> shortcut to Find & Replace in the current file.

Comment: @Jerry I've just tried that, I don't need to escape the quotes.